# List index out of bounds: 0 Error is in expression '{!saveAndSend}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page createorderpdf: Class.CreateOrderPDF

Tags: apex, controller

Please help me on this.

```html
<apex:page controller="CreateOrderPDFController">
    <apex:slds />
  
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body style="padding:10px 20px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
            <div style="width:90%;margin:auto;text-align:center;">
                <div style="margin:30px auto;text-align:center;display:inline-flex;">
                    <apex:form >
                        <apex:inputText id="it" value="{!emailId}" label="Enter Email Id" styleClass="slds-input" style="width:250px;"></apex:inputText> 
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAndSend}" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Save And Send" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"></apex:commandButton>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"></apex:commandButton>
                    </apex:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.externalCss}"/>
    <div Style="width:100%;border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;">
        <br/>
        <table border="1" style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;margin-left:5%;width:90%;" >
            <tr> 
                <td rowspan="2" Style="width:30%;"> <center><apex:image width="100px" height="50px" value="https://c.cs58.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150l000000Dxpg&oid=00D0l000000Cz2s&lastMod=1516024036000" /></center>  </td>
                <td Style="width:35%;"> <p style="font-family:Ariel;"><center><b>PAN GULF TECHNOLOGIES PVT. LTD.</b></center></p>  </td>
                <td Style="width:35%;">   </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td Style="width:50%;"> <p style="font-family:Ariel;"><CENTER><b>ORDER</b></CENTER></p>  </td>
                <td Style="width:50%;"> Date:   <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}"> <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> </apex:outputText>  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;margin-left:5%;width:90%;" >
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" Style="margin-left:5%;"> Order Details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>PGT Job Number: </b> </td>
                <td>{!ord.Job_number__c} </td>
                <td><b>Signed copy of proposal (Yes / No):</b></td>
                <td>{!ord.Signed_Copy_Of_Proposal__c}</td>
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <td><b>Hourly rate achieved: </b></td>
                <td>{!ord.Hourly_Rate_Achieved__c}</td>
                <td><b>Change Order Rate:</b></td>
                <td>{!ord.CO_Rate__c}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Hourly rate (as per Budget): </b></td>
                <td>{!ord.Budgeted_Contract_Rate__c}</td>
                <td><b>Client Job Number:</b></td>
                <td>{!ord.Client_Job_Number__c}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                
                <td><b>Total order value:</b></td>
                <td>{!ord.amount__c}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        
        <table border="1" style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;margin-left:5%;width:90%;">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5" Style="margin-left:5%;"> Order Breakup Details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th Style="text-Align:center;"> Name</th>
                <th Style="text-Align:center;">Type</th>
                <th Style="text-Align:center;">Amount</th>
            </tr>
            
            <apex:repeat value="{!ordItem}" var="l">
                <tr>
                    <td Style="text-Align:center;">{!l.Unit_Name__c} </td>
                    <td Style="text-Align:center;">{!l.Type__c} </td>
                    <td Style="text-Align:right;">{!l.Amount__c} </td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" Style="text-align:center;">Total </td>
                <td Style="text-Align:right;">{!ord.Amount__c}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table Class ="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" style="border-collapse: collapse;width:90%;margin-left:5%;">
            <tr><td>
                Yours Faithfully,<br/>
             <b>Pan Gulf Technologies Pvt.Ltd.</b><br/>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ord}" var="o">
                    <b><apex:outputText id="enq" escape="false" value="{!o.owner.name}" /></b>
                </apex:repeat> <br/>
           <!--     <b><apex:outputText id="role" escape="false" value="{!ord.owner.userrole}" /></b><br/> -->
                </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

```java
public class CreateOrderPDFController {
    
    public String emailId{get;set;}
    List<Wrapper> wrapperList = new List<Wrapper>();
    Id orderId;
    public  Opportunity oppty{get;set;}
    public Order ord{get;set;}
    public quote qt{get;set;}
   // Quote quote;
    public List<Quote_Line_Item__c> quoteLineItems{get;set;}
    public List<QuoteLineItem> lineItems{get;set;}
    public List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordItem{get;set;}
    public CreateOrderPDFController()
    {
        orderId = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('ID');
        System.debug('I am geting the Order Id::-'+orderId);
        ord = [SELECT Id,Name,Enquiry_Name__c,Vendor_Value__c,Remark_for_Approval_authority__c,Invoicing_Basis__c,Kind_Attention__r.name,PGT_Business_Division__c,Contract_Start_Date__c,Contract_End_Date__c,QuoteId,EffectiveDate,(SELECT Id FROM Attachments),Billing_Terms__c,OpportunityId,Job_number__c,TotalAmount,owner.name,CRM_Enquiry_No__c,Opportunity.Service__c,Opportunity.Connection_Design_Required__c,Account.name,opportunity.name,Estimated_Man_Hours__c,No_Of_Man_Hours__c,Signed_Copy_Of_Proposal__c,PO_Contract_Attached__c,amount__c,Budgeted_Contract_Rate__c,Hourly_Rate_Achieved__c,CO_Rate__c,owner.userrole.name,Client_Job_Number__c,Total_Credit_Period_in_Days__c,opportunity.PG_Entity_for_Business__c,opportunity.account.Payment_Format__c from Order where Id=:orderId];
        ordItem = [SELECT Id,Unit_Name__c,Type__c,Amount__c from Order_Line_Item__c where Order__c=:ord.Id];
        System.debug('OrderItem---'+ordItem);
        oppty = [SELECT Id, PG_Entity_for_Business__c,Name,Connection_Design_Required__c,Detailing_Software__c,CurrencyIsoCode,Account.Name,Project_Name__c from Opportunity where Id=:ord.OpportunityId];
        qt=[SELECT Id,Total_Man_Hours__c from quote where opportunityId=:oppty.id];
        quoteLineItems = [SELECT Id, Unit_Name_New__c,Inputs_Required__c,Inclusion__c,Exclusion__c from Quote_Line_Item__c where Quote__c=:ord.QuoteId];
        lineItems = [SELECT Id,Unit_Name__c,Type__c,Quantity,UnitPrice,TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId=:ord.QuoteId];
    }
    public pageReference saveAndSend()
    {
        
        Attachment a;
        System.debug('i am start to debugging'+orderId);
        
        for(String key : emailId.split(','))
        {
            wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(key));
        }
        String[] addresses = new string [wrapperList.size()];
        String[] ccAddresses = new string [wrapperList.size()];
        
        system.debug(orderId);
        list<contentdocumentlink> cdlList =[SELECT Id,linkedentityid,ContentDocumentId from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid=:orderId];
        system.debug('Attachment'+cdlList );
        string td1='"border:1px solid green; width=200px;"';
        string td2='"width=200px; border:1px solid green; background-color:red; color:white; font-weight:bold;"';
        string tdHead='"border:1px solid green; width=200px; color:white; background-color:green; font-weight:bold;"';
   
        List<ContentVersion> cvList = [SELECT VersionData, FileExtension,title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cdlList [0].ContentDocumentId AND IsLatest = true];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < wrapperList.size(); i++) {
            
            addresses[i] = wrapperList[i].email;
        }
        email.setSubject('Order Sheet');
        email.setToAddresses(ccAddresses);
        email.setToAddresses(addresses); //Used SOQL to retrieve addresses in the address
        // email.setToAddresses(customerEmail);
        string htmlBody ='<p>Hi Team,</p><p><span style="color:brown; font-weight:bolder;"></span>Please provide a new Job Order Number for the project:'+ord.CRM_Enquiry_No__c+'</p>'
            +'<p><left><table style="border:3px solid green; border-collapse:collapse;">'
            +'<tr><td style='+tdHead+'>Order Details:</td><td style='+tdHead+'></td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Enquiry Number</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.CRM_Enquiry_No__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Department</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.PGT_Business_Division__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Client Name</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Account.name+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Project Name</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Enquiry_Name__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Client Job Number</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Client_Job_Number__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Estimated Man Hours</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Estimated_Man_Hours__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Negotiated Man Hours</td><td style='+td1+'>'+qt.Total_Man_Hours__c+'</td></tr>'
             +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>BD Name</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.owner.name+'</td></tr>'
             +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Entity For Business</td><td style='+td1+'>'+oppty.PG_Entity_for_Business__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Connection Design</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Vendor_Value__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Invoicing Terms</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Invoicing_Basis__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Kind Attention/Client POC</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Kind_Attention__r.name+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Software Used</td><td style='+td1+'>'+oppty.Detailing_Software__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>BD Additional Comments </td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Remark_for_Approval_authority__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Total order value</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.amount__c+'</td></tr>'
             +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Business Currency</td><td style='+td1+'>'+oppty.CurrencyIsoCode+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Connection Design</td><td style='+td1+'>'+oppty.Connection_Design_Required__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>CO Rate</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.CO_Rate__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Invoicing Basis %</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Billing_Terms__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>PO Available</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Signed_Copy_Of_Proposal__c+'</td></tr>'
          //  +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Client Job Number</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Client_Job_Number__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Hourly rate achieved</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Hourly_Rate_Achieved__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Contract Start Date</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Contract_Start_Date__c+'</td></tr>'
            +'<tr><td style='+td1+'>Contract End Date</td><td style='+td1+'>'+ord.Contract_End_Date__c+'</td></tr></table></P>'
         /*   +'</br><p><left><table style="border:3px solid green; border-collapse:collapse;">'
            +'<tr><td style='+tdHead+'>Order Breakup Details:</td><td style='+tdHead+'></td></tr>'
            +'<tr><th Style="text-Align:center;"> Name</th><th Style="text-Align:center;">Type</th> <th Style="text-Align:center;">Amount</th> </tr>'
            +'<apex:repeat value='+ordItem+' var="l">'
            +'<tr><td Style="text-Align:center;">'+l.Unit_Name__c+' </td> <td Style="text-Align:center;">'+l.Type__c+' </td> <td Style="text-Align:right;">'+l.Amount__C+'</td></tr>'
            +'</apex:repeat>'
            +' <tr><td colspan="2" Style="text-align:center;">Total </td><td Style="text-Align:right;">'+ord.Amount__c+'</td> </tr>'
            +'</table></p>' */
            +'</table><p>Thanks & Regards,</br>'+ord.owner.name+'</p>'
            ;
        
        email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody); 
        email.setSubject('New order created for the project '+ord.CRM_Enquiry_No__c);
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment emlAtt  = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        Blob fileData = cvList[0].VersionData; // <= This step converts the version data into a blob for the attachment
        emlAtt.setFilename(cvList[0].title+'.' + cvList[0].FileExtension);
        emlAtt.setBody(fileData);
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {emlAtt });
        
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 
        
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+orderId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
        
    }
    public pageReference cancel()
    {
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+orderId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
    
    public class Wrapper{
        public String email{get;set;}
        public Wrapper(String i){
            email = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList =[SELECT Id,linkedentityid,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where linkedentityid=:orderId];
```

If no records are fetched in the above SOQL query, **`cdlList[0]`** will throw List index out of bounds error.

```
List<ContentVersion> cvList = [SELECT VersionData, FileExtension,title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cdlList [0].ContentDocumentId AND IsLatest = true];
```

The same will happen for above SOQL query too.

To avoid this, check if the List has records after the SOQL statement executes. If not use a return statement.

```
//add after SOQL
if(cdlList.isEmpty()){
 return;
}

//add after SOQL
if(cvList.isEmpty()){
 return;
}
```